# Is it possible to know if a NFT was sold in OpenSea?

Tags: nft, erc-721, events, opensea, transfer

Is it possible to detect, by looking at the `transfer` events, whether a NFT was sold from a Marketplace or not?

Basically I want to know if, in these cases, the `safeTransferFrom` method notifies the `transfer` event as if the `from` address is the owner of the token or if it does it using the actual address of the smart contract that is taking care of the sale.

Comment: I would like to know too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't be straightforward to use the `Transfer` event. Instead, you may want to use the `item_sold` and the `item_transferred` events provided by OpenSea.

You can listen to them by using their [Stream API](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/stream-js#readme).

You can subscribe to the collection you want with this code:

```
import { OpenSeaStreamClient, Network, EventType } from '@opensea/stream-js';
import { WebSocket } from 'ws';

const client = new OpenSeaStreamClient({
    network: Network.TESTNET,
    token: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    connectOptions: {
        transport: WebSocket
    }
});

client.onEvents(
    'YOUR_COLLECTION_SLUG',
    [EventType.ITEM_SOLD, EventType.ITEM_TRANSFERRED],
    (event) => {
      console.log(event)
    }
);
```

This is a example of the `item_sold` event:

```
{
  event_type: 'item_sold',
  payload: {
    closing_date: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.000000+00:00',
    collection: { slug: 'tm-nissan-370z-nismo-1-8' },
    event_timestamp: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.000000+00:00',
    is_private: false,
    item: {
      chain: [Object],
      metadata: [Object],
      nft_id: 'mumbai/0xa2bf19b63976fe14542e27ae7713f2bce34ce2bb/3845549538239791443866238707771342366788264520871453379120441143580141027409',
      permalink: 'https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/mumbai/0xa2bf19b63976fe14542e27ae7713f2bce34ce2bb/3845549538239791443866238707771342366788264520871453379120441143580141027409'
    },
    listing_type: null,
    maker: { address: '0xfe02781cc0fe76bfd2d211430bfa97d2889fd853' },
    order_hash: '0x931e8da185fef54e85bc5b89c08758460d8d9a76d65dcf69b07a2d537f7d6d19',
    payment_token: {
      address: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      decimals: 18,
      eth_price: '0.000471660000000',
      name: 'Matic',
      symbol: 'MATIC',
      usd_price: '0.849912000000000000'
    },
    protocol_address: '0x00000000000000adc04c56bf30ac9d3c0aaf14dc',
    protocol_data: { parameters: [Object], signature: null },
    quantity: 1,
    sale_price: '1000000000000000',
    taker: { address: '0x45dd8e9387d773a652f16afd54e61898ff3e6549' },
    transaction: {
      hash: '0x0276cf554d9d056e840ac51bd3f870840ee01f3ce251eb5cfe839b28d18cf238',
      timestamp: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.000000+00:00'
    }
  },
  sent_at: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.802491+00:00'
}
```

And this is a example of the `item_transferred` event:

```
{
  event_type: 'item_transferred',
  payload: {
    collection: { slug: 'tm-nissan-370z-nismo-1-8' },
    event_timestamp: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.000000+00:00',
    from_account: { address: '0xfe02781cc0fe76bfd2d211430bfa97d2889fd853' },
    item: {
      chain: [Object],
      metadata: [Object],
      nft_id: 'mumbai/0xa2bf19b63976fe14542e27ae7713f2bce34ce2bb/3845549538239791443866238707771342366788264520871453379120441143580141027409',
      permalink: 'https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/mumbai/0xa2bf19b63976fe14542e27ae7713f2bce34ce2bb/3845549538239791443866238707771342366788264520871453379120441143580141027409'
    },
    quantity: 1,
    to_account: { address: '0x45dd8e9387d773a652f16afd54e61898ff3e6549' },
    transaction: {
      hash: '0x0276cf554d9d056e840ac51bd3f870840ee01f3ce251eb5cfe839b28d18cf238',
      timestamp: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.000000+00:00'
    }
  },
  sent_at: '2023-05-22T03:41:37.698849+00:00'
}
```

The list of possible events you can listen can be found in the `EventType` definition:

```
export declare enum EventType {
    ITEM_METADATA_UPDATED = "item_metadata_updated",
    ITEM_LISTED = "item_listed",
    ITEM_SOLD = "item_sold",
    ITEM_TRANSFERRED = "item_transferred",
    ITEM_RECEIVED_OFFER = "item_received_offer",
    ITEM_RECEIVED_BID = "item_received_bid",
    ITEM_CANCELLED = "item_cancelled",
    COLLECTION_OFFER = "collection_offer",
    TRAIT_OFFER = "trait_offer"
}
```